# Classicthesis: Capital abbreviations for acronyms in Acronym section

Tags: acronyms, classicthesis, capitalization

I'm writing my thesis with classicthesis and I have some issues with the acronym package together with classicthesis.

The following code shows a minimal reconstruction of my problem:

```
\documentclass[]{scrbook}
\usepackage{classicthesis}
\usepackage{acronym}

\begin{document}

\begin{acronym}
  \acro{ABC}[ABC]{A B C}
\end{acronym}

\end{document}
```

This code compiles to:
[image: compilation with classicthesis activated]
where I would like to see: [image: compilation with classicthesis deactivated].

The second image was created with the classicthesis package commented out.

How can I enforce classicthesis to leave the capitalization of acronyms in the acronym list as they are?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `acronym` environment internally uses the `description` environment, but the `classicthesis` package changes the way `description` item labels are displayed. The `scrbook` class also makes its own changes.

With just `scrbook`, the item labels are displayed in bold sans-serif:

```
\documentclass{scrbook}

\begin{document}

\begin{description}
 \item[ABC] A B C
\end{description}

\end{document}
```

[image: ABC A B C]

Adding `classicthesis` changes the item label to small-caps:

```
\documentclass{scrbook}

\usepackage{classicthesis}

\begin{document}

\begin{description}
 \item[ABC] A B C
\end{description}

\end{document}
```

[image: ABC A B C]

The `acronym` package additionally sets the item format (within the `acronym` environment) to use `\aclabelfont` which defaults to using bold:

```
\documentclass{scrbook}

\usepackage{classicthesis}
\usepackage{acronym}

\begin{document}

\begin{acronym}
  \acro{ABC}[ABC]{A B C}
\end{acronym}

\begin{description}
\item[\aclabelfont{ABC}] A B C
\end{description}

\end{document}
```

[image: abc A B C abc A B C]

Now there's a warning message in the transcript:

```
LaTeX Font Warning: Some font shapes were not available, defaults substituted.
```

The problem here is that there's no bold small-caps font available, so the bold small-caps has been replaced with just bold lower case.

You can restore `scrbook`'s formatting for the `description` environment using:

```
\renewcommand{\descriptionlabel}[1]{\hspace{\labelsep}\descfont #1}
```

For example:

```
\documentclass{scrbook}

\usepackage{classicthesis}
\usepackage{acronym}

\renewcommand{\descriptionlabel}[1]{\hspace{\labelsep}\descfont #1}

\begin{document}

\begin{acronym}
  \acro{ABC}[ABC]{A B C}
\end{acronym}

\begin{description}
\item[\aclabelfont{ABC}] A B C
\end{description}

\end{document}
```

This produces:

[image: ABC A B C ABC A B C]

Comment: This _exactly_ solved my problem. But still, I wonder why this happens. The author of classicthesis uses scrreprt in his example code and the same happens there, too... Anyways, it now works for me!