# How to obtain a description item starting with a capital letter using classicthesis?

Tags: bold, classicthesis, small-caps, description

Consider following MWE:

```
\documentclass{report}

\begin{document}

\begin{description}
\item[Apple] apple
\item[\textbf{Apple}] apple
\item[apple] apple
\end{description}

\end{document}
```

which gives

[image]

When using the [`classicthesis` package](https://ctan.org/pkg/classicthesis) with following MWE :

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{classicthesis} %<--

\begin{document}

\begin{description}
\item[Apple] apple
\item[\textbf{Apple}] apple
\item[apple] apple
\end{description}

\end{document}
```

one observes that the capital letter in 'Apple' has been removed and a `sc` is applied:

[image]

This seems to be the expected behaviour, as mentioned in [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/227944/classicthesis-capital-abbreviations-for-acronyms-in-acronym-section).

How can I achieve a normal `bf` text starting with a capital letter?

- Boldface: using `\textbf{}` (see second figure)
- Capital letter: ???

Comment: `\item[\textbf{\uppercase{a}pple}] apple` should do it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Of course this goes against the spirit of `classicthesis` which is *never ever use boldface*. Anyway, here it is:

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{classicthesis}

\renewcommand{\descriptionlabel}[1]{%
  \hspace*{\labelsep}\textbf{#1}%
}

\begin{document}

\begin{description}
\item[Apple] apple
\item[\textbf{Apple}] apple
\item[apple] apple
\end{description}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

You need to use a font that provides the boldface/smallcaps combination. As you've found out, Computer Modern and Latin Modern do *not* provide such a combination. In contrast, Times Roman does.

Second, you need to override the way LaTeX/classicthesis operate on the argument of `\item` in a `description` environment. See below for an example.

[image]

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{newtxtext} % or some other font that provides boldface/smallcaps combo
\usepackage{classicthesis} 
\newcommand\mybfsc[1]{\bfseries\scshape\MakeUppercase #1}

\begin{document}

\begin{description}
\item[Apple] rst
\item[\textbf{Apple}] uvw
\item[\textbf{\textsc{\MakeUppercase Apple}}] xyz % the brute-force way
\item[\mybfsc{Apple}] abc % with the help of a utility macro
\end{description}

\end{document}
```